# My website is showing apache test page

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services

I created website on Amazon Web Server. I route my ip to my domain using ROUTE 53 service. but now my website is showing APACHE TEST PAGE rather then content while if i enter my ip address/wordpress it's working properly.

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot to add a virtual host in http.conf. Apache restart is needed after this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html